# Why does the count of NUMA Nodes Influence Processor grouping

Tags: windows-server-2019, numa, logical-processor

On a HPE DL380 G10 Server with 2 Xeon(R) Gold 6246R (32 phys. Cores, 64 log. with HT), in the BIOS, using this setting:

> System Configuration > BIOS/Platform Configuration (RBSU) >
> Performance Options > Advanced Performance Tuning Options > NUMA Group
> Size Optimization

We can choose of these 2 options:

1. **Clustered** — Optimizes groups along NUMA boundaries, providing better performance.
2. **Flat** - Enables applications that are not optimized to take advantage of processors spanning multiple groups to utilize morelogical processors.

The "Clustered" Option will force Windows to only reporting ONE NUMA Node BUT 2 Processor Groups, each one 32 Cores.
The "Flat" Option on the other side shows 2 NUMA Nodes and only 1 Processor Group with 64 logical Cores.

Sure i know already a lot about NUMA and Processor groups, so i'm really not asking for any recommendations about the best Setting for my usecase or so.
Instead the question is: Why would it make sense for windows to decide to go with 2 Processor Groups when there is only one NUMA node and vice-versa? Also, i never found any documentation that Windows (Server 2019) Splits 64 Cores into 2 Groups, is this expected behaviour at all?

Comment: It seems quite logical to me that "NUMA boundaries" for Clustered mean the same as "CPU boundaries". Since you have two CPUs, you end up with two processor groups. "Boundaries" then means to respect the physical architecture. And you're right: Impossible to find any documentation on the subject.

Comment: I did find one supporting [article](https://ingogegenwarth.wordpress.com/2017/07/27/numa-settings/) which says: "The default setting is Clustered, which basically leads to the fact that Windows will create for each physical processor a processor group".

Comment: Hey harry :-) hmmm the article seems to just say exactly what i said: the grouping is happening with the Clustered setting. This "boundaries" thing... i would kind of understand it if there were 2 numa nodes and 2 processor groups. Still i gues the main question is why the hell does windows group processors < 65 cores. All documents say you must have > 64 cores for grouping

Comment: My understanding is that 64 is the maximum in a group, not the minimum.

Comment: Thats how it actually seems to be but reading https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/processor-groups says "Support for systems that have more than 64 logical processors is based on the concept of a processor group," AND "On systems with 64 or fewer processors, existing applications will operate correctly without modification."

Comment: This documentation dates from 2018 and applies up to Windows Server 2008. The clustered/flat options are not mentioned at all, so perhaps didn't exist at that time. The fact that it doesn't relate at all to what you are seeing, to me this means that it's outdated and should not be used for understanding Windows Server 2019.

Answer (score 3):

The article you have found dates from the year 2008. At that time Windows was
confronted with NUMA computers with more than 64 processors, while its implementation
of processor groups was limited to 64. The solution then was to create automatically
more than one such groups of no more than 64 processors each.

A more flexible solution was introduced end 2014. The earliest reference I have found
is an
[HP Advisory note](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docLocale=en_US&docId=emr_na-c04650594)
regarding HP Gen9 servers and dating from  2015-04-24:

> In the Revision 1.30 (12/24/2014) and later versions of the System ROMs for Gen9 servers, a **new ROM-Based Setup Utility, "NUMA Group Size Optimization,"** has been added that allows the user to change the behavior of reporting processors to the Operating System. This option will allow the OS to put all logical processors into a single group if there are 64 logical processors or fewer ("Flat".)

The Clustered option creates one processor group for the cores of each CPU.
The Flat option is intended to let applications use all the computer cores,
since in Windows by default an application is limited to a single group and therefore
will see and use only its one group.

Regarding your questions:

> Why would it make sense for windows to decide to go with 2 Processor Groups when there is only one NUMA node and vice-versa?

This is dictated by the Clustered option, which makes sense for an application
and all its processes and threads to execute all of them on nearby memory
for performance.

If an application needs in your case more than 32 cores, you should use the Flat
option, to make all cores disponible.

> I never found any documentation that Windows (Server 2019) Splits 64 Cores into 2 Groups, is this expected behaviour at all?

Yes, this is the expected behavior.
It's not very well documented, but there are references for this behavior,
for example
[Exchange performance:HP NUMA BIOS settings](https://ingogegenwarth.wordpress.com/2017/07/27/numa-settings/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the investigations you did! It is clear that it obviously does what it does but unfortunately we still don't have any information about how it looks from windows perspective. All infos from HP basically just say like "it is as it is, we force windows to do some magical stuff" and the HP advisory points to the same MS Article from 2018 that i linked above (which again says that grouping needs at least 64 cores.. Did i overlook anything?

Comment: That's where is the main confusion: The article you found is marked as from 2018, but it's not. It applies at most to Windows Server 2008, which means that it was written in 2008. The 2018 date is probably the result of some automatic modification by the Microsoft website software (or an employee updating some format); it was not written on that date. It's now 13 years old, an eternity for computers.

Comment: Interesting, Still the HP advisory liks to that article (and i didnt find any newer one), leaving me clueless and having no evidence that windows (e.g. 2019) is expected to group processors under 64 cores and also no clue how the decisions for grouping connects to NUMA nodes.

Comment: The rules you yourself listed in your post : flat/clustered. The advisory note links to that article for information about Processor Groups, which it describes with great detail.

Comment: Sorry but i really don't get what you mean. Can yuo confirm "the link in the advisory note that describes it in great detail" is this link? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd405503(v=vs.85).aspx  So the aricle from 2008?

Comment: The advisory note was mostly concerned with the compatibility for the old way of doing it. The only method it lists is therefore the "flat" (which is the previous method that is no longer the default), and it gives a link to the 2008 article of Microsoft to explain what happens then and what is a Process Group (with lots of internal details). The way I see it, it's basically saying that there is new stuff, but not to worry the old is still there.

Comment: Hmm if i get your comments right, that all unfortunately just says "it is as it is, take it as given". I can't believe that there is no evidence from Windows perspective about how the building of processor groups can be influenced. Also i can't believe HP builds something into their servers that uses undocumented windows features.

Comment: The lack of information may indicate that Microsoft keeps its liberty to change whenever and whatever it likes. Being opaque is usually intentional.

Comment: Sorry i cannot reward your answer because it just says that it is as it is but i truly honor your efforts, therefore the upvote. To be clear, your answer does not deliver much more information than the question already does: on this HP server with that setting, Windows behaves like this. The backgrounds of it stay totally unclear.

Comment: Your decision of course. The reason why these two options exist are very clearly to satisfy two kinds of applications: intensive users of local resources; intensive users of multiple cores.

Comment: ...Since the first kind are more common, Clustered is the default.

Comment: Hehe well the application perspective is a whole different story, don't wanna dive into that topic here ;-) From my perspective as a professional developer, "Clustered" to be default only makes sense for applications that have special support for processor groups which there are not many of them available AFAIK. Anyway, that truly exceeds the scope here :D

Comment: I disagree, since the question was "Why?". Applications that don't belong to these two profiles will be happy with either one. The OS will prefer Clustered since it makes core-balancing easier for app loads. I really don't understand what you're still missing here, as you have all the information available and it's clearly understandable.

Comment: Well the question was: "Why would it make sense for windows to decide to go with 2 Processor Groups when there is only one NUMA node and vice-versa?" Your answer only focusses on the HP specific part (and it just repeats facts that were already stated in the question)  but it misses the windows specific part, the one you think of "Microsoft keeps its liberty to change whenever and whatever it likes" - sorry i should have wrote a much more detailed question i guess

Comment: The answer I'm trying to pass over is "Because this NUMA node contains two distinct CPUs, each with its own resources such as cores, functional units and cache memory". Taking the hardware architecture into account is essential for performance, which is the main goal of any OS. That's why Clustered is preferred - performance, and that's why it makes sense for Windows to prefer two Processor Groups, one per each CPU.